# Replacing matched string with another

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to create a search box , to look for the searched pattern in html tags like p,span,etc,just like the ctrl+f option of the browser.

Javascript :

```
function searchKeyword(){
        var keyword = document.searchform.searchbox.value;
        $("#paragraph").each(function() {
            var string = $(this).text();
            newstring = string.replace(keyword, '<span style="background-color: #faf701;">'+keyword+'</span>');
            $(this).text(newstring);
        });
    }
```

The only issue is that,it doesn't read the string as a html markup,but as a simple string and it outputs exactly:

```
<span style="background-color: #faf701;">'+keyword+'</span>
```

Instead of a highlighted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), since you want to render the html content use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$(this).html(newstring);
```

---

Since you have id selector, there is no need to use `.each()`

```
function searchKeyword() {
    var keyword = document.searchform.searchbox.value;

    $("#paragraph").html(function (i, html) {
        return $(this).text().replace(keyword, '<span style="background-color: #faf701;">' + keyword + '</span>');
    })
}
```

---

Use a regex to replace multiple matches

```
function searchKeyword() {
    var keyword = document.searchform.searchbox.value;
    var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(keyword), 'g')

    $("#paragraph").html(function (i, html) {
        return $(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="background-color: #faf701;">' + keyword + '</span>');
    })
}


if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}
```

Comment: i just found that this script i'm using doesn't replace multiple matchings,can you give me an idea on how to solve that?